# Uploading to the cheeseshop different versions of a package for different versions of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, distribution, distutils, pypi

I have an open-source Python project (called GarlicSim), and I maintain 4 different versions of it for Python versions 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 and 3.1. Yes, maybe it's unusual, but I like using as much features as possible. I keep them in 4 different forks of the repository.

Now I want to upload my project to the cheeseshop. What's the way to do this? I expect that a user will automatically get the version of GarlicSim appropriate for his Python version. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you tell if you’re using distutils or setuptools?  Also, depending on the tool used on the receiving end (easy_install vs. pip), what the user will get varies.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I didn't find a solution and abandoned this scheme of providing a different version of the library for each version of Python.

Answer (score 3):

```
python2.4 setup.py bdist_egg upload
python2.5 setup.py bdist_egg upload
python2.6 setup.py bdist_egg upload
python3.1 setup.py bdist_egg upload
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? For example, is it okay if all versions have the same name or will it mess things up?

Comment: Yeah, it's fine to have different versions; several projects do this including, one of mine: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster/